# Unable to create ASP.NET Core Web Application but not getting error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I try to create a ASP.NET Core Web Application project, I get to choose a template, but all I get is an empty solution with no projects added. If I try to add a new project, the same thing occurs. I do not get any error messages for most of the templates (such as Web application which I'm trying to start), if I choose "Razor Class Library" I get the an error referencing to the `ActivityLog.xml` which has this as the latest entry:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Interop.IVsClientBuildManagerService.DispatchUserWorkItem(IVsClientBuildManagerEventSink
>   sink)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.CBM.CBMWorkItemDispatcher`1.Dispatch(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer, Func`1 toExecute, Action`1 callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Razor.RazorImportsProvider.Microsoft.Html.Editor.ContainedLanguage.Razor.Def.IRazorImportsProvider.GetImportsAsync(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer, Func`1 toExecute, Action`1 callback)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Razor.Implementation.Shims.RazorCodeGenerator.DispatchGetRazorNamespacesWorkItem()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Razor.Implementation.Shims.RazorCodeGenerator.<.ctor>b__24_0()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.Utility.GuardedOperations.InvokeExtensionPoint(Object
>   errorSource, Action action)
> --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
>   exceptionObject)

**How I got here:**
I had a working VS2017 installation without ASP.NET Core & Web workload. I installed the latest version of the `.NET Core SDK`, then I upgraded to the latest version of VS2017 and included the ASP.NET Core & Web workload as well as the Blazor Language Services extension [as described here](https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html).

**What I've tried:**
After this, I couldn't create any projects at all and got errors for `Unsupported Project Types`, same even for my my old C# projects. I searched extensively and eventually uninstalled everything and reinstalled twice, but the same errors. So I uninstalled again, using all the cleaner tools, ran the console with the reconfigure commands, installcleaner commands and everything I could find as well as removing the VS directories and appdata directories. After that I am where I am now. I would think I have a very clean VS installation, now regular console applications and winforms applications work, but no the .NET Core Web applications.

How can I get this fixed? How can I generate a better log file to attach here for more information?

**Edit:**
When I check the solution directory, a project is being created but not added, if I try to add this as existing project I get the following error message:

> Expected 1 export(s) with contract name
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory+ProjectLoadHelper"
>   but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.

Comment: Is it a problem if you uninstall and then reinstall VS?

Comment: @DejanJanjušević As I stated I uninstalled and reinstalled three times before posting this, yet it still doesn't work. Tried to clean as much as possible in between as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add MvcRazorCompileOnPublish in your Project

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>       
   <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
   <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: After adding the line, and trying to add the project as existing, I get the following error `Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory+ProjectLoadHelper" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.`

Comment: Oh, It seems this error is actually displayed when adding as existing project even before adding that line. Editing OP.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this was fixed after completely uninstalling, cleaning up visual studio directories (and AppData) and reinstalling, and then *again* clearing the folder found in:

> %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7cfaf63e\ComponentModelCache

Even though I had done this step before, this is what finally fixed it for me. An important note here is to clear the folder found in the **Local** AppData folder, most answers I've found only reference the Roaming folder, so to be sure it's a good idea to clear all of them. I hope this helps someone else in a similar situation!